# Is projection of locally-connected-like compact subset locally-connected-like?

Tags: gn.general-topology

#### Definition

A (topological) space $(X, \mathcal{T}_X)$ has property $P$ (locally-connected-like), if every open cover has an open connected refinement.

#### Problem

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}_X)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ be spaces, $Z = X \times Y$, $\mathcal{T}_Z$ be the product topology on $Z$, $f : Z \to X$ be defined by $f(x, y) = x$, and $C \subset Z$ be compact and have property $P$.

Does $f[C]$ have property $P$?

#### Background

- A space is *compact* if every open cover has a finite subcover.
- A space $(X, \mathcal{T}_X)$, where $\mathcal{T}_X$ is a topology on $X$, is *locally connected*, if for each $x \in X$ and $U \in \mathcal{T}_X(x)$ there exists connected $V \in \mathcal{T}_X(x)$ such that $V \subset U$.
- Hence, locally connected implies $P$. But not vice versa.
- The analogous question for local connectedness was solved at [Is projection of locally connected compact subset locally connected?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/416561/32487). The present question is a continuation of that question.
- The goal is to find a property which is equivalent to local connectedness on Hausdorff spaces, but which is preserved by projection from compact subsets.
- The space $Y$ in the above linked answer has property $P$ but is not locally connected, and hence that counter-example does not apply to this question.
- Property $P$ is equivalent to local connectedness on a large class of spaces (see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4392055/51161) to [Locally connected iff every open cover has a connected refinement?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1815821)), but not equivalent on all spaces.
- Property $P$ is preserved by open maps, and more generally by maps which map open connected subsets to open subsets.
- When $Z$ and $X$ are spaces where $P$ is equivalent to local connectedness, a quotient map $Z \to X$ preserves local connectedness (and hence $P$).
- [Is the restriction of a projection to a compact subset a quotient map?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/414344/32487) provides conditions for $f\restriction C$ being a quotient map. However, as shown there, $f\restriction C$ is not always a quotient map.
- Because the result holds in so many cases, it is rather tricky to form a counter-example. The other (desired) possibility is that the result does hold.

Comment: Apologies for getting the wrong answerer name in my edit.  I got confused because MSE scrolls away from the linked answer while rendering MathJax.

Comment: @LSpice No worries! Your edits were good:)